# creating a IOBlockStorageDriver in mac os x Leopard

Tags: xcode, macos, iokit

How can one create a simple IOBlockStorageDriver in mac os x leopard. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the XNU kernel and the drivers which ship with Mac OS X are open source:

http://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1066/

The [driver for the Intel PIIX ATA controller](https://opensource.apple.com/source/AppleIntelPIIXATA/AppleIntelPIIXATA-251.0.1/) seems a good fit for what you're looking for. Maybe you can use it as an example to work from.

For general Mac OS X kernel information, I've found the book *Mac OS X Internals* by Amit Singh very useful.

Depending on the type of driver you're trying to write, you might want to look into the example Filter Scheme Driver provided by Apple, and the similar "Simple Crypto Disk" example from the aforementioned book. The source code is available at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164013/https://osxbook.com/book/src/)